# Error importing devserver module devserver.modules.sql: "cannot import name util"

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-dev-server

Just upgraded from django 1.8 to 1.9 and getting this error while migrating:

Error importing devserver module devserver.modules.sql: "cannot import name util"

Although they say it is fixed it here:
https://github.com/dcramer/django-devserver/issues/131

```sh
[localhost] local: python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/halit/project_folder/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/halit/project_folder/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 324, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/halit/project_folder/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/halit/project_folder/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/halit/project_folder/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/halit/project_folder./venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/devserver/models.py", line 40, in <module>
    load_modules()
  File "/home/halit/project_folder/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/devserver/models.py", line 25, in load_modules
    raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured, 'Error importing devserver module %s: "%s"' % (name, e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing devserver module devserver.modules.sql: "cannot import name util"

Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'python manage.py migrate'

Aborting.
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem. Editing the usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/devserver/modules/sql.py file and changing the import on line 15 from:

`from django.db.backends import util`

to

`from django.db.backends import utils`

Seemed to do it. I had to change all the references in the file from `util` to `utils`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, well... I can't just change the modules of a third party application (devserver in this case) because it is not going to work on the server anyway.

Comment: You could presumably fork the repo and then point pip at your version in github, I think?